# Getting 404 while hitting my get url in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am New to node So a bit confused after seeing some code here some example below

Simply I just want a add some apis to this existing project , But for some Reason Its getting 404 error

Here app.js

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");
var cors = require("cors");
var config = require("./config.config");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
var fs = require("fs");

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

var app = express();

mongoose.connect(config.databaseUrl, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(" database connectivity ", error);
  } else {
    console.log(" database connect successfully");
  }
});

if (!fs.existsSync("./app/attachments/")) {
  fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/");
  fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/task");
  fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/product");
  fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/companyicon");
} else {
  if (!fs.existsSync("./app/attachments/product"))
    fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/product");
    
  if (!fs.existsSync("./app/attachments/companyicon"))
    fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/companyicon");
}
if (!fs.existsSync("./app/pdf")) fs.mkdirSync("./app/pdf");
// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.use(
  fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024 },
  })
);
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "app")));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);

// app.get('/api/invoice/invoice', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.send({ message: "Working!", status: true });
// });

require("./app/router/user.router")(app);
require("./app/router/project.router")(app);
require("./app/router/contactCategoery.router")(app);
require("./app/router/productCategoery.router")(app);
require("./app/router/client.router")(app);
require("./app/router/projectStatus.router")(app);
require("./app/router/clientBrief.router")(app);
require("./app/router/invoice.router")(app); /// Here i added the invoice router >>>>>>>>>>>>>


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('first', req);
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;

app.listen(config.port, (req, res) => {
  console.log("server start at " + config.port);
});
```

here invoice.router.js

```
module.exports = (app ,http) => {
    var invoice = require("../controller/invoice.controller");

    app.post("./api/invoice/invoice", invoice.create);
    app.get("./api/invoice/invoice", invoice.fetch);
}
```

Here invoice.controller.js

```
exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({ message: "Working!", status: true });
}


exports.fetch = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('now >>>>>>');
    res.send({ message: "Working!", status: true });
}
```

here config.js

```
var url = 'http://hosturl.com';
var port = "8001";
var databaseUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/<dbname>";
var username = "<user>";
var password = "<password>";



module.exports = {
  // url: url,
  port: port,
  databaseUrl: databaseUrl,
  username: username,
  password: password,
  PaytmConfig: PaytmConfig,
  price: price,
  smsgateway: smsgateway,
  nodemailer: nodemailer,
  ProjectStates: ProjectStage,
  ClientBriefQuestions: ClientBriefQuestions,
  DesignStyle: DesignStyle,
  ContactCategoery: ContactCategoery,
  SpendCategories: SpendCategories,
  Column: Column,
  sms: sms,
};
```

While Requesting othe Get apis that works fine but while requesting

`http://localhost:8001/api/invoice/invoice` its Getting 404 working Kindly Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base paths are incorrect, it should be:

```
app.post("/api/invoice/invoice", invoice.create);
app.get("/api/invoice/invoice", invoice.fetch);
```

Comment: sure i know that !

Answer (score 1):

Edit your invoice file to this.

```
    module.exports = (app ,http) => {
        var invoice = require("../controller/invoice.controller");
    
        app.post("/api/invoice/invoice", invoice.create);
        app.get("/api/invoice/invoice", invoice.fetch);
    }
```

Let us start from there

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const createError = require("http-errors");
const path = require("path");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const config = require("./config.config");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const fs = require("fs");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");


  //db connection
mongoose.connect(
    config.databaseUrl,
    { useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true, 
      useCreateIndex: true, 
      useFindAndModify: false 
    }).then( () => {
      console.log("database connect successfully")
  }).catch( err => {
      console.log("ERROR CONNECTING ", err)
  })



if (!fs.existsSync("./app/attachments/")) {
  fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/");
  fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/task");
  fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/product");
  fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/companyicon");
} else {
  if (!fs.existsSync("./app/attachments/product"))
    fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/product");
    
  if (!fs.existsSync("./app/attachments/companyicon"))
    fs.mkdirSync("./app/attachments/companyicon");
}
if (!fs.existsSync("./app/pdf")) fs.mkdirSync("./app/pdf");
// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.use(
  fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024 },
  })
);
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "app")));
app.use(cors());



// app.get('/api/invoice/invoice', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.send({ message: "Working!", status: true });
// });


// import app routes
const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const invoice = require("./router/invoice.router"); /// Here i added the invoice router >>>>>>>>>>>>>


require("./app/router/user.router")(app);
require("./app/router/project.router")(app);
require("./app/router/contactCategoery.router")(app);
require("./app/router/productCategoery.router")(app);
require("./app/router/client.router")(app);
require("./app/router/projectStatus.router")(app);
require("./app/router/clientBrief.router")(app);


// app routes
app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/api/invoice/invoice", invoice);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('first', req);
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;

app.listen(config.port, (req, res) => {
  console.log("server start at " + config.port);
});
```

here invoice.router.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();

const invoice = require("../controller/invoice.controller");


app.post("/", invoice.create);
app.get("./", invoice.fetch);



module.exports = router;
```